# Proximal Operator / Mapping of $\frac{1}{2} {\|x\|}^2 + \delta_{\mathbb{R}_+^n}\left(x\right)$: Sum of $L_2$ Norm Squared and Indicator Function

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, normed-spaces, proximal-operators

Let $$f(x) = \frac{1}{2}\|x\|^2 + \delta_{\mathbb{R}_+^n}(x)$$

(componentwise nonnegtive).   How to find $$\operatorname{prox}_{\alpha, f}(z)$$

I know

1. $\operatorname{prox}_{\alpha, \frac{1}{2}\|\cdot\|^2}(z) = \frac{1}{1+\alpha}z$
2. The definition: $$\operatorname{prox}_{\alpha, f}(z) = \arg\min_x\bigg(\frac{1}{2\alpha}\|x-z\|^2 + f(x)\bigg)$$

So we have $$\operatorname{prox}_{\alpha, f}(z) = \arg\min_x\bigg(\frac{1}{2\alpha}\|x-z\|^2 + \frac{1}{2}\|x\|_2^2 + \delta_{\mathbb{R}_+^n}(x) \bigg)$$ 
and then
$$\operatorname{prox}_{\alpha, f}(z) = \arg\min_{x\in \mathbb{R}_+^n}\bigg(\frac{1}{2\alpha}\|x-z\|^2 + \frac{1}{2}\|x\|_2^2 \bigg)$$

Comment: Complete the square to absorb the quadratic term into the quadratic term that appears in the proximal operator definition.

Comment: By the way, that comma doesn't need to be there in your proximal operator definition, because you are in fact evaluating the proximal operator of the function $\alpha f$.

Comment: @littleO  I am confused what you mean about complete square here. I remove the indicator function. Then it seems that it becomes the prox of $L_2$ norm square?

Comment: Actually don't remove the indicator function. Combine the two quadratic terms into one single quadratic term by "completing the square". You can do that by first expanding the quadratic terms, then collecting like terms, then adding and subtracting a certain constant to make a square appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity I'll assume that $\alpha = 1$. You want to evaluate
$$
x^\star = \arg \min_x \quad I(x) + \frac12 \|x\|^2 + \frac12 \|x - z \|^2
$$
where $I$ is the indicator function of the nonnegative orthant.
We'll combine the two quadratic terms into a single quadratic term by completing the square.  Notice that
\begin{align}
&\frac12 \|x \|^2 +\frac{1}{2} \|x - z \|^2 \\
&= \frac12 \|x\|^2 + \frac12 \|x\|^2 - \langle x,z \rangle + \frac12\|z\|^2 \\
&= \|x\|^2 - \langle x,z \rangle + \frac12 \| z\|^2 \\
&= \underbrace{\|x\|^2 - 2 \langle x,z/2\rangle + \|z/2\|^2}_{\text{perfect square}} - \|z/2\|^2 + \frac12 \|z\|^2\\
&= \left\|x - \frac{z}{2} \right\|^2 + \text{terms that do not depend on $x$}.
\end{align}
Therefore,
$$
x^\star = \arg \min_x \quad I(x) + \|x - \frac{z}{2} \|^2.
$$
Computing $x^\star$ has now been reduced to evaluating the prox-operator of $I$.